# Possibility of using stream-table join in KSQLDB to implement LAG-like functionality

Tags: ksqldb

Suppose I have a materialised view aggregate on a source stream, and then perform a stream-table join on the same source stream and the previous aggregated table. When I insert a value `v` into the source stream, will the join output

- the result of aggregation after including `v`
- the result of aggregation before including `v`
- non-deterministic  result

I tried with some experiment and it seems like the second options is the case:

```
CREATE STREAM c_events (id STRING KEY, value INT, time TIMESTAMP) with (KAFTA_TOPIC='c_events', VALUE_FORMAT='json', PARTITIONS=3, timestamp = 'time');
CREATE TABLE latest_c_events AS SELECT id, latest_by_offset(value) AS latest_value, latest_by_offset(time) AS latest_time from c_events group by id;
CREATE STREAM enriched_c_event AS
    SELECT c.id, c.value, c.time, l.latest_value, l.latest_time
    FROM c_events c
    LEFT JOIN latest_c_events l ON l.id = c.id;
```

When performing inserts operation:

```
INSERT INTO c_events VALUES ('id-1', 1, '2023-06-22T00:00:00Z');
INSERT INTO c_events VALUES ('id-1', 2, '2023-06-22T00:00:01Z');
INSERT INTO c_events VALUES ('id-1', 3, '2023-06-22T00:00:02Z');
```

The results of `enriched_c_event`  is:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|C_ID             |VALUE            |TIME             |LATEST_VALUE     |LATEST_TIME      |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|id-1             |2                |2023-06-22T00:00:|1                |2023-06-22T00:00:|
|                 |                 |01.000           |                 |00.000           |
|id-1             |3                |2023-06-22T00:00:|2                |2023-06-22T00:00:|
|                 |                 |02.000           |                 |01.000           |
```

If this is the case, is this pipeline a good idea to implement PostgreSQL `LAG()` function?